# How to extract a substring from column in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've a column in oracle that stores values in keys. Just for example-

| Column_name |
| --- |
| ((key1="value1" AND key2='value1') OR (key1="value1" AND key2='value2')) |
| ((key1="null" AND key2='value3') OR (key1="value1" AND key2='value4')) |

I want to only extract the value of key2 before OR clause (as there are 2 key2 in every row of this column)

Expected result:

| Column_name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| ((key1="value1" AND key2='value1') OR (key1="value1" AND key2='value2')) | value1 |
| ((key1="null" AND key2='value3') OR (key1="value1" AND key2='value4')) | value3 |

Can somebody give me roughly an idea how to do this?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we can describe your logic as extracting the *first* `key2` value, we can try using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with a capture group:

```sql
SELECT col, REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, 'key2=''(.*?)''', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS key
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't know why but I'm getting only null as an output. Also can you please explain what all those three 1s mean in the query? I know the first 1 to is to pick first matching of "key2" substring only not sure about the rest.

Comment: First 1 means start at position 1, second is to take first match, third 1 is for first capture group.

Comment: Thank you. I just got to know my error, actually the value1 of key2 is inside single quotation not in double quotation. But I'm unable to put singe quotation as it terminates the string. I've updated my question, see for reference.

Comment: @PrateekGautam Answer updated assuming that the first `key2` would always be inside single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: @ Prateek Gautam as a hint when you have this type of extraction and maybe you don t have knowledge about regexp is better always to search for a pattern in your data and start from there.in your data the pattern is the word "or" or you can take the second parenthesis as a pattern.  with regular text functions build in in sql we can extract the desired  output