# Retrieve unique value from a row string in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am getting result in the URL column, as follows

```
tracking=http://test-trk-801v.pii-dmz.ext:8080/95078&analysis=http://test-trk-801v.pii-dmz.ext:8080/95078-analysis/index.jsp
tracking=http://localtest-mi-track16.localperc.cloud:11080/232819&analysis=http://localtest-mi-anlys19.localperc.cloud:9080/232819-analysis/index.jsp
tracking=http://test-trk-002.pii-dmz.ext:10088/77971
tracking=http://test-trk-003.pii-dmz.ext:14080/92542
tracking=http://localtest-mi-track04.localperc.cloud:15080/203396&dentalanalysis=http://localtest-mi-anlys12.localperc.cloud:8080/203396-analysis-dental/index.jsp&analysis=http://localtest-mi-anlys03.localperc.cloud:12080/203396-analysis/index.jsp
tracking=http://localtest-mi-track03.localperc.cloud:14080/202161&bonescananalysis=http://localtest-mi-anlys03.localperc.cloud:10088/202161-analysis-bonescan/index.jsp&analysis=http://localtest-mi-anlys03.localperc.cloud:10088/202161-analysis/index.jsp
tracking=http://test-trk-002.pii-dmz.ext:10088/7732
tracking=http://test-trk-003.pii-dmz.ext:14080/92902
tracking=http://localtest-mi-track16.localperc.cloud:11080/236978&analysis=http://localtest-mi-anlys19.localperc.cloud:9080/236978-analysis/index.jsp
```

there are too many result of this pattern, I want to retrieve the unique `trk-` and `track` value from the first part like from `tracking=http://test-trk-801v.pii-dmz.ext:8080` the value `trk-801v` similarly from `tracking=http://localtest-mi-track16.localperc.cloud:11080` the `track16`.

Like I have `trk-801v,trk-002,trk-003` unique and similarly `track16, track04` unique.

Comment: Please post your current code and describe the issue you have with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract a substring from column in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72038716/how-to-extract-a-substring-from-column-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm) for this:

```sql
select distinct regexp_substr(my_column, 'trk-\d+\w+|track\d+') from my_table
```

This query will extract first substring matching regex `trk-\d+\w+|track\d+` from you column, and will return it. If nothing matches, it will return `NULL`

Demo can bee seen [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/plDmq3WG).